# playwright dosen't works well in pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, playwright

i try to pack my code into exe
but when i do what github ask me to do
it's not working

```
CALL py -m venv venv  
CALL venv\scripts\activate  
CALL pip install playwright pyinstaller  
CALL SET PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0  
CALL playwright install chromium  
CALL pyinstaller -y -F main.py --add-data "venv/lib/site-packages/playwright/driver;playwright/driver".
```

#it said that playwright haven't been installed#
when i check that file i can not install it as well